# How do I return a row from one table with the number of matching id's from a second table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables, one of discussions and one of responses. I'm wondering how to pull back each discussion row along with the number of rows from the responses table with the matching discussion ID.

### table `discussions`

- `id`
- `creator`
- `date`
- `title`

### table `responses`

- `id`
- `creator`
- `date`
- `discussion_id` = this is `id` from `discussions`

So I'd love to be able to get each row of discussions along with a COUNT() of all the `responses` rows that have its `discussion_id`

This is about as far as I got:

```
SELECT
    d.id,
    d.creator,
    d.date,
    d.title,
    (select count(select * from r where r.discussion_id = d.id) from r) num
FROM 
    discussions d, responses r
```

Am I on the right track here?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Why not using grouping function

Comment: That sounds promising, I didn't know that even existed. Thanks I'll check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. Try:

```
SELECT
    d.id,
    d.creator,
    d.date,
    d.title,
    (select count(*) from r where r.discussion_id = d.id) num
FROM 
    discussions d
```

Comment: Ah, that worked perfectly! Thanks a ton. I created a view using this query and this'll make things alot easier.

Comment: this solution is a correlated subquery. they don't perform well on large data sets. stick with the join.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT d.id, d.creator, d.date, d.title, COUNT(r.id) AS num 
FROM discussions AS d 
  INNER JOIN responses AS r ON r.discussion_id = d.id
GROUP BY d.id
```

As pointed out by Crwydryn you could also use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of the `INNER JOIN`. The difference would be that you also count the discussions with no resonses with the `LEFT JOIN` - the `num` column will then be `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this...simply use group by....it will give what u want

```
 SELECT
        d.id,
        d.creator,
        d.date,
        d.title,
       (Select Count(*) from response where response.id= d.id) as num
    FROM 
        discussions d
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following Query

```
SELECT
    d.id,
    d.creator,
    d.date,
    d.title,
   count(r.id)  NUM
FROM 
dicussion d join response r on d.id = r.discussion_id  
GROUP BY d.id
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a LEFT JOIN. A standard join will return only Discussions that have a related Response entry, so if the response count is 0 (i.e. no responses for that discussion), a query with a standard join won't return that discussion record. Also, this is more performant than a subquery.

```
select d.id,
    d.creator,
    d.date,
    d.title,
    count(r.id) as num
FROM discussions d 
    LEFT JOIN responses r on d.id = r.discussion_id
GROUP BY d.id
```